Uncaught SyntaxError with DOMPurify 3.1.6 and 2.4.9: Invalid Regular Expression due to ${...} in Minified Files
I was using DOMPurify 2.3.10 with Gulp for minifying files, and everything worked fine. However, after upgrading to versions 3.1.6 or 2.4.9, I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //gm),DATA_ATTR=seal(/: Unmatched ')'

In version 3.1.6, the code is:
    MUSTACHE_EXPR = seal(/\{\{[\w\W]*|[\w\W]*\}\}/gm),
ERB_EXPR = seal(/<%[\w\W]*|[\w\W]*%>/gm),
TMPLIT_EXPR = seal(/\${[\w\W]*}/gm),
DATA_ATTR = seal(/^data-[\-\w.\u00B7-\uFFFF]/),
ARIA_ATTR = seal(/^aria-[\-\w]+$/);

In version 2.3.10, the code is:
MUSTACHE_EXPR = seal(/\{\{[\w\W]*|[\w\W]*\}\}/gm),
ERB_EXPR = seal(/<%[\w\W]*|[\w\W]*%>/gm),
DATA_ATTR = seal(/^data-[\-\w.\u00B7-\uFFFF]/);

It seems like Chrome is treating the ${[\w\W]*} in TMPLIT_EXPR as a template literal and replacing it with an empty value, causing the syntax error. How can I fix this issue using Gulp or another method without introducing other problems?
Thanks in advance!

The error message has //gm but the code only has /gm. The error can't be coming from the code you posted.

Effectively, your assumption seems to be correct. What happens if you replace const TMPLIT_EXPR = seal(/\${[\w\W]*}/gm); by const TMPLIT_EXPR = seal(/\$\{[\w\W]*\}/gm); in the source code? I don't really understand why they didn't escape it like they did it for MUSTACHE_EXPR!
